# the power set of every well-ordered set is well-ordered implies well ordering

Tags: axiom-of-choice, well-orders

I'm new to set theory and ordinals and such things and currently have a question.

I have a proposition which says that the axiom of choice is equivalent to this: "the power set of every well-ordered set is well-ordered."

It's trivial that the statement is true by well-ordering (which is equivalent to axiom of choice). but I can't find the proof in the opposite way. I also have a proof which I can't understand. It seems that the author tried to prove well-ordering (for any sets) using the mentioned statement. but I can't get it.

**Note that I need to prove well-ordering using the mentioned statement not proving the statement with or without AC!**

This is the proof: [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGR7b.png)

Comment: The key problem is that the Axiom of Regularity (or Foundation) plays a significant role in this proof. So it's often not easy to explain from a naive point of view.

Comment: The proof you link to seems to have some typos, though.